# Outliers returning NA

Tags: r

I am using the below function to find outliers using 3*sd but in the results I am getting outliers and NA values. There should not be NA values in the outliers right?

how do I fix it?

```
findingoutlier<- function (data, cutoff=3, na.rm=TRUE){
  sd <- sd(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  mean <- mean(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  outliers <- (data[data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd])
  return (outliers)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily remove NA using this:

```
outliers <- outliers[!is.na(outliers)]
```

So your function will look like this:

```
findingoutlier<- function (data, cutoff=3, na.rm=TRUE){
  sd <- sd(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  mean <- mean(data, na.rm=TRUE)
  outliers <- (data[data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd])
  outliers <- outliers[!is.na(outliers)]
  return (outliers)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly subtle outcome of the way that `NA` comparisons are handled in R.

Suppose you have an `NA` value in `data`. Then your criterion

```
data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd
```

evaluates to `NA` (i.e., we don't know if the unavailable data point is an outlier or not ...)

What do we get if we ask for `data[NA]`?  From `?"["`:

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character ‘NA’ index
> picks an unknown element and so returns ‘NA’ in the corresponding
> element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character
> result ...

(this is a technical way of saying "`NA` in, `NA` out").

So you should either drop `NA` values from your input (e.g. with `na.omit()`, or use

```
!is.na(data) & (data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd)
```

as your criterion.

I can't think of any other reasons you would end up with `NA` in output (and since you haven't given a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I can't guess what they would be ...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing a vector of integers in the data parameter.
`outliers <- (data[data < mean - cutoff * sd | data > mean + cutoff * sd])`.

With a silly example set `a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` this is searching for `data < -3.215838 | data > 13.21584` which doesn't find a match.

I would default to using a package for [outliers](http://r-statistics.co/Outlier-Treatment-With-R.html).

```r
install.packages("outliers")
library(outliers)

values <- c(1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
outlier(values)
# prints [1] 8
```

Another option for time series data is Twitters package on [anomaly detection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection)

```r
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(AnomalyDetection)

values <- c(1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
dates <- as.POSIXlt(c('2010-3-01', '2010-3-02','2010-3-03', '2010-3-04', '2010-3-05', '2010-3-06', '2010-3-07', '2010-3-08', '2010-3-09', '2010-3-10', '2010-3-11', '2010-3-12', '2010-3-13', '2010-3-14', '2010-3-15', '2010-3-16', '2010-3-17', '2010-3-18'
))
df <- data.frame(dates, values)
res = AnomalyDetectionTs(df, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=TRUE)
res$anoms
res$plot
#    timestamp anoms
# 1 2010-03-04     8
```

[image]